# Different databases identify in registry

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I need to know what database they come from when doing the select, the uni using UNION, they are 5 different databases with the same fields

```
SELECT *, DB_NAME()[DATABASE] FROM SMKNEW.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, DB_NAME()[DATABASE] FROM DH.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, DB_NAME()[DATABASE] FROM FE.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, DB_NAME()[DATABASE] FROM PSQ.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, DB_NAME()[DATABASE] FROM RH.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
```

[image: Query Dabatase Name Master]

I need to know what database they come from when doing the select, the uni using UNION, they are 5 different databases with the same fields

Try this too..
[image]

How could I know what data base the registry is from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the DB name in your query, so why not just doing like the following

```
SELECT *, 'SMKNEW' as [DATABASE] FROM SMKNEW.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, 'DH' as [DATABASE] FROM DH.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, 'FE' as [DATABASE] FROM FE.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, 'PSQ' as [DATABASE] FROM PSQ.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
UNION ALL SELECT *, 'RH' as [DATABASE] FROM RH.dbo.COLABORA WHERE CB_CODIGO LIKE '%11%'
```